# Density of open sets in finer topology

Tags: general-topology, zariski-topology

Let $X$ be any topological space endowed with two topologies
$\mathcal{T} \subset \mathcal{T}'$ (the later means that
$\mathcal{T}'$ refines $\mathcal{T}$, that is every open subset
$U \subset X$ with respect $\mathcal{T}$ (ie $U \in \mathcal{T})$ is
already open with respect $\mathcal{T}'$.

Assume that $X$ is irreducible (or say more weaker connected;
irreducible implies connected) with respect $\mathcal{T}$.
Connected means that if there exist
two $U,V$ which are open & cloled for $\mathcal{T}$ and
$X= U \dot{\cup}V $ then either $U$ or $V$ is empty. And irreducible
that every two non empty open $U, V \in \mathcal{T}$ intersect properly:
$U \cap V \neq \emptyset$.

Question: Are there any interesting sufficient or neccessary conditions
on $X, \mathcal{T}$ and $\mathcal{T}'$ known such that following holds

> every open non empty $U \in \mathcal{T}$ is 'dense' in $X$ with respect
> finer topology $\mathcal{T}'$

What I mean by 'interesting'? Well, everything non trivial/boring like
$\mathcal{T}= \mathcal{T}'$ or $\mathcal{T}= \{X, \emptyset\}$ etc.
Note that this question generalizes [this Question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1188401/zariski-dense-implies-classically-dense/4120013#4120013)
where $X \subset \mathbb{C}^n$ is a complex irreducible variety, $\mathcal{T}$
the Zariski topology and $\mathcal{T}'$ analytical topology on $X$ induced
by $\mathbb{C}^n$

Comment: So you’re interested in the case in which $U\cap V\ne\varnothing$ whenever $\varnothing\ne U\in\mathscr{T}$ and $\varnothing\ne V\in\mathscr{T}'$?

Comment: @Brian: 
Yes exactly, that's an equivalent characterization for $U \in \mathcal{T} $ to be
dense with respect topology $\mathcal{T}'$.